# Excel not getting column cells for my SQL INSERTS

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel worksheet + i'm trying to get the values of the columns in a seperate column.

This is what I have in excel:

```
INSERT INTO person (Name) VALUES ('"& C4 & "')
```

However, this doesn't get the value (it just stays like string).

What am I doing wrong?

I have tried:

```
'"=C4"'
'"$C4$"' 
'"=$C4"'
```

If I use the normal way of doing it (=C4 for the entire cell), the value gets updated.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Is that a worksheet formula?

```
 = "INSERT INTO person (Name) VALUES ('" & C4 & "')"
```

Answer (score 0):

insert into in a command in sql. I assume you have already loaded the excel into sql and now want to make changes in it.
Use the below line:
UPDATE person set name=concat(" ",name," ").

If this does not work, try to be more clear with the question so that we can help you better.